# What's wrong with this trivial proof Archimedean Property?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$ states that:

> Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^+,~b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\exists N\in\mathbb{N},~N\cdot a>b$.

And I know one of the regular proof that uses the Least Upper Bound property of $\mathbb{R}$. However, I don't know why the proof stated below have not been mentioned in analysis books ever.

**Proof:** Suppose $b\le0$, choose $N=1\in\mathbb{N}$, then $N\cdot a=1\cdot a=a>0$, therefore $N\cdot a>b$.
Suppose $b>0$, then choose $N=(\lceil\frac{b}{a}\rceil+1)\in\mathbb{N}$, then $N\cdot a=(\lceil\frac{b}{a}\rceil+1)\cdot a\ge(\frac{b}{a}+1)\cdot a\ge b+a>b$.

Comment: *ceiling* = "the smallest integer..." it sound very similar to "the least..."

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lceil x\rceil =\min\{n\in \mathbb {Z} \mid n\geq x\}$.

Comment: [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition) (or *least upper bound*) of $\displaystyle S$  is the number that "is less than any other upper bound" of $\displaystyle S$.

Comment: Yes. So what's wrong with my proof? Or, why don't the analysis books use this proof?

Comment: Nothing wrong... simply, to assert that the "ceiling" function "works" in $\mathbb R$, we have to apply the Least Upper Bound property.

Comment: @Eric how do we know that $f(x)= \lceil x \rceil$ is well defined for *every* real value $x$? My bet is that you think of this function in terms of the decimal representation of $x$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom
Well, I see. Can you help me give a prove that $f(x)=\lceil x\rceil$ is well-defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Eric any sensible proof would use, as an assumption, the Archimedian property. In particular, just showing that $x$ has a decimal representation requires the Archimedian property. In order for $x$ to have at most $n$ digits to the left of the decimal, it needs to be less than $10^n$.

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

The "gist" of the proof of the "trivial" fact expressed by the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), is to show that the *real line* as no elements that are "infinitesimal small".

Thus, speaking roughly:

> however small we choose $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and however big we choose $b \in \mathbb{R}$, we may always find a "suitable" $N \in \mathbb N$ such that, multiplying $a$ and $N$, the result will "exceed" $b$.

If we agree that we have to prove this "trivial" fact, appealing to the ceiling function here can be problematic: what happens with $\frac{b}{a}$ when $a$ is an "infinitesimal" ? Assuming that the division "makes sense", we may say that the result is an "infinite" quantity : $+ \infty$.

But if so, there is no $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $N=+\infty+1$...

More precisely, if $a$ is infinitesimal, the *quotient* of the division $\frac{b}{a}$ must be an $M$ such that $M a \le b \le (M+1) a$, and we are running in circle...